# Prevent from raising ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid or adding twice on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to change has_many association behaviour

considering this basic data model

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :skills_users
  has_many :skills_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, through: :skills_users, validate: true
  has_many :skills_users
end

class SkillsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill

  validates :user, :skill, presence: true
end
```

For adding a new skill we can easily do that :

```
john = User.create(name: 'John Doe')
tidy = Skill.create(name: 'Tidy')

john.skills << tidy
```

but if you do this twice we obtain a duplicate skill for this user

An possibility to prevent that is to check before adding

```
john.skills << tidy unless john.skills.include?(tidy)
```

But this is quite mean...

We can as well change [ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#<<](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/33a7eedc01a54c685723ad5a7795e332a5132ca1/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L1057) behaviour like

```
module InvalidModelIgnoredSilently
  def <<(*records)
    super(records.to_a.keep_if { |r| !!include?(r) })
  end
end 
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.send :prepend, InvalidModelIgnoredSilently
```

to force `CollectionProxy` to ignore transparently adding duplicate records.

But I'm not happy with that.

We can add a validation on extra validation on `SkillsUser`

```
class SkillsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill

  validates :user, :skill, presence: true
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :skill }
end
```

but in this case adding twice will raise up `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` and again we have to check before adding

or make a uglier hack on `CollectionProxy`

```
module InvalidModelIgnoredSilently

  def <<(*records)
    super(valid_records(records))
  end

  private

  def valid_records(records)
    records.with_object([]).each do |record, _valid_records|
      begin
        proxy_association.dup.concat(record)
        _valid_records << record
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      end
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.send :prepend, InvalidModelIgnoredSilently
```

But I'm still not happy with that.

To me the ideal and maybe missing methods on CollectionProxy are :

```
john.skills.push(tidy)
=> false
```

and

```
john.skills.push!(tidy)
=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
```

Any idea how I can do that nicely?

-- EDIT --

A way I found to avoid throwing Exception is throwing an Exception!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, through: :skills_users, before_add: :check_presence
  has_many :skills_users

  private

  def check_presence(skill)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if skills.include?(skill)
  end
end
```

Isn't based on validations, neither a generic solution, but can help...

Comment: Have you tried `has_many :skills, -> { uniq }, through: :skills_users`?

Comment: Is working only if you remove the validation `validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :skill }`

Comment: The main problem is this hide the truth.... Records are recorded on database, just not given through this special DISTINCT scope, isn't what I want.

Comment: Have you tried removing `validate: true` and using `validates_associated :skills` on User?

Comment: No because I use it on User and you can't use it on both side [WARNING: This validation must not be used on both ends of an association. Doing so will lead to a circular dependency and cause infinite recursion.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Oh sorry I read to fast `validate: true` and `validates_associated ` are the same thing

Comment: And to be honest isn't really the problem here.

Comment: @JoelAZEMAR It's just that I've never seen validation errors raising errors like that without the explicit use of bang(!). I've also never used `validate: true`, but have used `validates_associated` on `has_many` associations before and never had that side effect. My first guess was those methods were implemented differently, but I really didn't go into it.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim I play with a sample code and I can confirm you is exactly the same result. Here the problem is a bit more complex because ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#<< method tigger directly the record on database, and I guess is calling save! behind the scene...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps i'm not understanding the problem but here is what I'd do:

- Add a constraint on the DB level to make sure the data is clean, no matter how things are implemented
- Make sure that skill is not added multiple times (on the client)

Comment: Hi, I've already a constraint in database and is my concern, because without validation I obtain  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint` so the second part is what I try to do in a nicer manner than add a basic condition like `john.skills << tidy unless john.skills.include?(tidy)`

Comment: I don't think that messing with associations is any nicer or more readable for a one off problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the migration that created your SkillsUser table.
the better if you show me the indexes of SkillsUser table that you have.
i usually use has_and_belongs_to_many instead of has_many - through.
try to add this migration

```
$ rails g migration add_id_to_skills_users id:primary_key
# change the has_many - through TO has_and_belongs_to_many
```

no need for validations if you have double index "skills_users".
hope it helps you.

Comment: Isn't what I want. I want the `has_many` relation. I know HBTM behave differently